# Communication Between MS 2003 CA Server and Client - Non active directory environment :Design Query

Tags: security, cryptography, ldap, client-server, windows-server-2003

I have a scenerio where the CA and its clients are not in an active directory environment(win2003 enterprise).  They are located physically apart(different places).

For example,

```
*If the domain name is 'ExampleBank.org'*
*The CA name is 'ca.ExampleBank.org'  *
*CA type is Enterprise Root CA (online) [windows 2003 enterprise server]*
```

1. How will the certificates/CRLs be distributed by the CA in such a non active directory environment?
2. How will the clients send their CSR's to the CA?
3. Will ICERTREQUEST2 interface be usefull under such a scenerio to send a request to CA? (Submit call)
4. Do i need to look at LDAP approach?

Answer (score 0):

1. The CA will publish the certificates in a public server or in a LDAP server. So the certificates should be accessed via those URLs. The CRL's will be published periodically at the location pointed by the CRL distribution points field in the x509 certificate.
2. The CSR's can eb taken manually to the registration authority(if the CA has one) or this interface will be defined by the CA
3. I think, this interface is RPC based, so this should be valid only with in a Network. Can someone please clarify on this point?

Thanks